# Php: how to elegantly add a new method if you cant edit the base class?

Tags: php

lets say I have form inputs:

```
TextArea -> Input -> InputBase
Checkbox -> InputBase
RadioGroup -> InputBase
Password -> Input -> InputBase
```

They are untouchable class. But this time I want to add a new functionallity. e.g. "echo CSS class attributes", and a new field (numeric). Normally I would add to `InputBase` but this time its not an option.
I could do this normally:

```
Numeric -> Input -> InputBase
```

and where to add my custom functionallity? I could write:

```
Numeric -> MyCustomFunctionallityClass -?> InputBase
                                       -?> Input
```

but then MyCustomFunctionallityClass must inherits InputBase, so it loses `Input` nature.

Comment: Can't you inherit from Input, which seems to inherit from InputBase itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lookup [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

> Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies. The semantics of the combination of Traits and classes is defined in a way which reduces complexity, and avoids the typical problems associated with multiple inheritance and Mixins.

So, you can have:

```
trait Hello {
    public function sayHello() { echo 'Hello ';}
}

trait World {
    public function sayWorld() { echo 'World'; }
}

class MyHelloWorld {
    use Hello, World;
    public function sayExclamationMark() {
        echo '!';
    }
}

$o = new MyHelloWorld();
$o->sayHello();
$o->sayWorld();
$o->sayExclamationMark();
// outputs 'Hello World!'
```